# Hiding Output from Expect Commands

Tags: bash, shell, expect

so I have the following code and cant figure out how to only display one send command. I only need the result from the df -h send command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Updating Source..."

/usr/bin/expect << EXPECT
    log_user 0;
    spawn  -noecho ssh -p 7742 user@location
    expect "username:"
    send "username\r"
    expect "password:"
    send "password\r" 
    send "shell\r"
    send "df -h\r" 
    send "exit\r"
    sleep .5
    send "exit\r"
    interact
EXPECT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Updating Source..."

/usr/bin/expect << EXPECT
    log_user 0;
    spawn  -noecho ssh -p 7742 user@location
    expect "username:"
    send "username\r"
    expect "password:"
    send "password\r" 
    send "shell\r"
    log_user 1;
    send "df -h\r"
    log_user 0;
    send "exit\r"
    sleep .5
    send "exit\r"
    interact
EXPECT
```